# Single Signon - PingFederate - What might cause a session to expire?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, saml, pingfederate

1)  First, I know that the clocks between a user system and PingFederate (PF) needs to be within 5 min of each other.  Is the time PF sends me in its SAML the time PF is using?  Also can I set the difference between the clocks?

2)  Second, I am currently logging in to PingFederate but then am following an endless cycle of PingFederate saying I am logged in, and then my Rails app using Devise asking PingFederate again if I am logged in.  I checked that a session is getting set for that user.  Is there something that could cause the session to expire?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific with #2? What do your logs for Rails say? Does your browser just go into continuous redirects from Rails to PingFed and around again? Is Rails accepting the assertion? Is the session in Rails get instantiated and indicate that the user is authenticated? Does the user exist in the Rails app user DB?

Comment: I notice that you are looking for answers to the Rails question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372305/single-sign-on-what-gets-set-when-a-user-logins-using-devise-in-rails. I will answer your other one... Because #2 is def. a Rails/Devise issue.

Comment: I am running PF using thin so no log is created.  I tried running rails in ssl mode, but thin wasn't getting set to SSL mode because of force_ssl having a !dev line.  I tried to put the monkey patch for force_ssl to remove the !dev in config/initializers but that didn't work.  1)  Browser goes into continuous redirects from Rails to PF and back.  2)  The session is getting instantiated in warden for my user and I get that user back when I read the session.  The user exists in the Rails app user DB.

Comment: Actually I was able to put thin in debug mode, but didn't see any helpful output.

Comment: It's not a problem on the PingFed side. It's a problem on your Rails side.

Comment: Can you answer the first question?  Can I set the difference PF users between the clocks?

Comment: I did answer the first question. PF uses UTC as required by SAML-Core. This is not configurable, beyond changing the time on your server (NOT in PingFed). Why? Because there is no reason to use any other time in PingFed other than UTC. Why? Because no standard serviced by PingFed allows for any other time to be used.

Comment: My question is: The clocks between the SP and IDP cannot have more than a certain difference between them.  Is it possible to set this difference? Thanks.

Comment: After re-reading your response, I think I get it, the difference is 5 minutes, and is not configurable, right?

Comment: No... It's configurable in the SP connection. Just remember that the bigger the time window, the bigger the hole in security.  And for servers that are time synched, a 10 minute window should be about 595 seconds more than needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All times sent in assertions in PingFederate (and all other products) are in UTC as defined by the [SAML-Core](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf) (Pg. 9, Line 310, section 1.3.3) standard. Your "SP" endpoint/application should be using the same when calculating time differences, to be SAML-compliant.
2. As I've stated in my comments, this is definitely a Rails issue. The assertion isn't "expiring" - your app just isn't creating an authenticated session. SAML doesn't provide for a length of how long the user's authentication is valid for.